# JavaScript кликабельные ссылки

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста как написать JavaScript который бы делал все ссылки кликабельными. Просто есть некоторые форумы где приходится постоянно выделять самому так как они просто текстовые. Браузер мозилла и хром

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- FF [Linkification](https://addons.mozilla.org/ru/firefox/addon/linkification/)
- Chrome [Linkification](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/linkification/cflchafndefoljnhhholeekfpgmbphaf)

Comment: спасибо Юр, то что и нужно было